# Get changes from updated base branch into my feature branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-branch

I have a `topical` which was taken `development` branch. Now `topicalBranch` is ahead by a commit, and meanwhile `development` accepts pull requests from some other contributors, and the updated merge on `development` has conflicting changes from my latest commit `C4`.

So the current tree looks like:

```
C1---C2---C5 development
      \
      C3---C4 topicalBranch
```

I want the new tree to look like:

```
C1---C2---C5 development
           \
           C3'---C4' topicalBranch
```

where C3' and C4' have changes from C5. I looked up [Git-Rebasing](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing), but I want `topicalBranch` to be updated, without making any changes to `development`.

What is the best way to update my `topicalBranch` with the changes made on `development` branch, so that I can make a new pull request to `development` branch.

Comment: Indeed, `git rebase` is the answer you are looking for. Why did you think that was not right for you?

Comment: That is because if I rebase `topicalBranch` on `development`, won't it make `development` replay my changes on it?

Whereas what I want is to get the new changes from `development` to `topicalBranch`.

I maybe totally wrong in assuming this.
If someone can give a detailed explanation on this?

Comment: @shubhamsingh yes, if you have checked out development, and you rebase topical then that will happen. What Bryan is saying is that you should checkout topical, and then rebase development.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII thanks for the clarification, I get that now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) is definitely what you want. However, **note** that this will rewrite your history. So if you're pushing to a remote repository from where other developers are pulling your topicalBranch, then they will have to force or rebase pull. But if you're the only one working on topicalBranch, then this is not a problem.

Let's reconstruct your scenario by initializing a new repository and making some commits to demonstrate what the tree will look like after a rebase.

```
jeff ~ $ mkdir test && cd test
jeff test $ git init
```

> ```
> Initialized empty Git repository in /home/jeff/test/.git/
> ```

```
jeff test (master #) $ touch file1 && git add . && git commit -m "init repo"
```

> ```
> [master (root-commit) ba3e0ed] init repo
>  1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
>  create mode 100644 file1
> ```

```
jeff test (master) $ git branch -m development

jeff test (development) $ touch file2 && git add . && git commit -m "file2"
```

> ```
> [development fb03bd9] file2
>  1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
>  create mode 100644 file2
> ```

Now let's branch off to topical.

```
jeff test (development) $ git checkout -b topicalBranch
```

> ```
> Switched to a new branch 'topicalBranch'
> ```

```
jeff test (topicalBranch) $ touch file3 && git add . && git commit -m "file3"
```

> ```
> [topicalBranch c9ffa5a] file3
>  1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
>  create mode 100644 file3
> ```

```
jeff test (topicalBranch) $ touch file4 && git add . && git commit -m "file4"
```

> ```
> [topicalBranch 5322397] file4
>  1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
>  create mode 100644 file4
> ```

And simulate a commit pulled in from other developers.

```
jeff test (topicalBranch) $ git checkout development
```

> ```
> Switched to branch 'development'
> ```

```
jeff test (development) $ touch file5 && git add . && git commit -m "file5"
```

> ```
> [development e237fb5] file5
>  1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
>  create mode 100644 file5
> ```

Now we can see that the tree is like yours and we want to get the new commit from the development branch into the topicalBranch.

```
jeff test (development) $ git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all
```

> ```
> * e237fb5 (HEAD -> development) file5
> | * 5322397 (topicalBranch) file4
> | * c9ffa5a file3
> |/  
> * fb03bd9 file2
> * ba3e0ed init repo
> ```

So let's rebase.

```
jeff test (development) $ git checkout topicalBranch
```

> ```
> Switched to branch 'topicalBranch'
> ```

```
jeff test (topicalBranch) $ git rebase development
```

> ```
> First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
> Applying: file3
> Applying: file4
> ```

And finally you can see that the topicalBranch has its history re-written to include the new commits from the development branch before.

```
jeff test (topicalBranch) $ git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all
```

> ```
> * f332250 (HEAD -> topicalBranch) file4
> * a069799 file3
> * e237fb5 (development) file5
> * fb03bd9 file2
> * ba3e0ed init repo
> ```

Now you will be able to easily fast-forward merge topicalBranch into development.

This process can be repeated over as often as need be for new commits coming into the development branch. I recommend doing this often so that conflicts can be periodically resolved instead of having a litany of conflicts to resolve when the topicalBranch is finally finished - moreover, this will help you discover configuration and architectual drifts early on.

Comment: I think this answer has too little explanation and too much commands + console output.

Comment: @jeff Thanks for the detailed answer with commands. I replicated a local git repo using these, and I noticed that `rebase` makes my history 'linear' rather than having a branched history with updated changes in `topicalBranch` and without touching `development` branch.

Comment: Rebasing `topicalBranch` to be based on commit `C5` rather than `C2` has no effect on branch `development`. Even though the ancestry chain from the head of `topicalBranch` back through to commit `C1` now (temporarily) **looks** linear, the two branches remain distinct, and new commits on branch `development` will **not** automatically go into `topicalBranch`.

Comment: @Roman thanks for the suggestion, I have updated my answer with a better narrative for future readers.

Comment: @BryanPendleton good point! I have updated my answer with your caution including a recommendation to repeat this process regularly to keep the topicalBranch up to date.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to merge the development branch into your topical branch, so it will look more like

```
C1---C2--------C5 development
      \         \
      C3---C4---C6' topicalBranch
```

So you need to do `git merge development` from your topical branch.

Comment: this is a good answer as an alternative to `rebase` if others are pulling so that the history remains in tact, in consideration of the tradeoff for a messy tree versus easy pulls.